# How remove unnecessary dependencies in output from "gradle dependencies" task?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build-tools

Assume, we have multi-project build and we want to see all dependencies for certain module:

```
gradle certainProject:dependencies
```

Then we will get similar output:

```
+--- project :firstProject
|    +--- project :anyProject
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 1.7.36
|    +--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20 -> 1.18.22
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.22 -> 5.3.25 (*)
+--- project :secondProject
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 1.7.36
|    +--- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.8.6 (*)
|    +--- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final
|    \--- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final
+--- project :thirdProject
|    +--- … e.t.c
```

I'm interesting in only see "project :" in output recursively in depth:

```
+--- project :firstProject
|    +--- project :anyProject
+--- project :secondProject
+--- project :thirdProject
```

Probably exclude by pattern or smth same?

These deps add such way:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(
            project(":firstProject"),
            project(":secondProject"),
            project(":thirdProject"),
    )
    
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:3.2.2")
    //…
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can, why do you want to?

Comment: Obviously, to see only projects dependencies in multiple-project build ;)

Comment: Have you tried using `--scan` to send a scan of the build to the public build scan service? There's a dependencies section in the UI, and you can just open the project you care about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it absolutely necessary for some reason that this be solved only with arguments to `gradle`?

If not, then this will produce what you want:

```bash
gradle certainProject:dependencies | grep -E ' project \:'
```